# Windows 8 metro style - game engines

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

Are there any game engines available for a Windows 8 metro style application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several game frameworks you can use to develop Metro Style games:

C++/DirectX:

- CoCos2D http://cocos2d-x.org/news/54

C#

- MonoGame which is great if you have an XNA code base, http://monogame.codeplex.com/ And as stated above SharpDX is a C# framework that wraps DirectX. MonoGame also uses SharpDX

HTML5:

- EaselJS - http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS
- ImpactJS - http://impactjs.com/

Standalone Editors:

- Construct 2 is another tool that supports Windows 8, compiling down to HTML5 - http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/272/how-to-make-a-windows-8-metro-app/page-1.
- GameSalad now has support as well - http://gamesalad.com/creator/windows-8

Comment: Need not to say anything- The answer has come from a Microsoft guy #respect

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe any proper game engines have been ported to win8 yet (as of this writing) ... so you will currently need to write directly to the DirectX libraries.

If you use C#, take a look at SharpDX: http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/

Answer (score 0):

Another two cents:

- Delta Engine http://deltaengine.net/
- Ogre Engine http://www.ogre3d.org/